# How to fix the 'downloadable font rejected by sanitizer' error?

Tags: css, fonts

Tonight I came across a strange error when trying to use a font on my NeoCities site. I placed a font I had downloaded into my code the same way I have with many other fonts, but it never showed up on my website. I thought it might be an error in time so I waited for a few minutes, refreshed the page, and tried again; the font still wasn't there, but when I opened my site up on my iPod it *was* there. I figured it must be a Firefox issue so I opened up the Inspect menu and came across the following errors:

[a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDA7I.png)

(I'm not sure why the superscript font is now showing it has issues as it seems to display fine, but as it's here I figured I should include it anyways.)

I've tried searching around, but I haven't been able to find any answer for this. All my files are in the same folder together, and there are only two fonts that won't work for me.

The codes for some of the fonts I have in my stylesheet are here (only three as if I post all of them  get marked as spam):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Pixel_Operator"; 
    src: url("https://pixelmoondust.neocities.org/fonts/site%20fonts/PixelOperator.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "pixie";
    src: url("https://pixelmoondust.neocities.org/fonts/site fonts/pixie.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "bitsy";
    src: url("https://pixelmoondust.neocities.org/fonts/site%20fonts/BITMAP_FONT__BitsyButton_by_Emotikonz.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

and the ones that won't show up for me are pixie and bitsy. They both show up on my iPod, both on Safari *and* Firefox, so I really don't know why they won't show up on desktop. If you want to see this for yourself, my website is [PixelMoondust](https://pixelmoondust.neocities.org/home) and I've changed the main font of my dropbar to bitsy and my main content (the middle of my page) font to pixie so that both the ones I'm having an issue with are present on any of my pages. For me, those two sections of my page show a standard serif font. Below I will also include the sections of my code where I have added the fonts to their sections:

```
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'bitsy';
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: url("https://pixelmoondust.neocities.org/cursors/pink/pink%20cursor.png"), default;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```
.content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(40, 1, 76, 0.63), rgba(40, 1, 76, 0.63)), url("https://pixelmoondust.neocities.org/backgrounds/stars3.gif");
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20%;
  width: 65%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-left: solid;
  border-top: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #9b7ede;
  border-size: 2px;
  font-family: "pixie";
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I've used other downloaded fonts in these same sections and truly don't know what the issue is :/ Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: the font file is most likely corrupted, try and download it from another source